# Remove the duplicates in a list but the first preference should not be removed according to counts

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two lists 'myarray' and 'u'.List 'myarray' contains the names and their counts are in the list 'u'.I want to remove the duplicates in myarray and their counts in u.but i want the first preference to remain their.

```
myarray=['1.2','2.3','1.00','1.2','1.2','4.7','4.7','3.2','5.5','1.2','4.7'];
u=['hi','hello','bye','hi','hi','nice','ok','yup','i', 'heya', 'ok'];
```

i have used this method but how does it fail?

```
m=list(set(myarray))
print('myarray',m)
counts=list(set(u))
print("counts",counts)
```

desired output:

```
 myarray=[1.2,2.3,'1.00','4.7',4.7',3.2,'5.5','1.2']
 u=['hi','hello','bye','nice', 'ok','yup','i','heya']
```

Comment: where does it fail?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Does it boil down to "remove duplicates while keeping the order"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try something like this:

```
myarray=['1.2','2.3','1.00','1.2','1.2','4.7','4.7','3.2','5.5','1.2','4.7']
u=['hi','hello','bye','hi','hi','nice','ok','yup','i', 'heya', 'ok']

new_array = []
new_u = []
for word, count in zip(u, myarray):
    if word in new_u:
        continue
    else:
        new_array.append(count)
        new_u.append(word)

print(new_array)
print(new_u)
#  ['1.2', '2.3', '1.00', '4.7', '4.7', '3.2', '5.5', '1.2']
#  ['hi', 'hello', 'bye', 'nice', 'ok', 'yup', 'i', 'heya']
```

Comment: thanks it solved my problem :)